# JQuery: After adding some AJAX, some of the jquery code no longer works

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Here's a pastebin link to my entire jQuery code. [ http://pastebin.com/w57ma5Gx ]  The "Thumbnails" section was working fine before I added the ajax sections.  Anyone can help me with why it quit working? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) click handler on your thumbnails, which I assume are getting replaced by your ajax call, instead of the 'classic' click handler:

```
$("img.thumbs").live("click", function()                                
{
    var imgLink = $(this).attr("src");                                     
    $("img#spotlight").attr("src", imgLink);                       

});
```

That way, you will attach a click handler *"for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future"*.